# Does Ubuntu or Xubuntu have a toggle window borders option?

Tags: 20.04, xubuntu, window-manager

I am using Kubuntu 20.04. My favourite feature of it, is that I was able to map a keyboard shortcut to toggle the window borders / controls of a particular window.

Now I am looking at switching to gnome or xfce, since plasma has too many bugs for me.

Do either Ubuntu or Xubuntu offer the same option of toggling window borders with a keyboard shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

This looked like something fun! I did some research and hopefully this helps you. (Did not test this in Ubuntu, only Xubuntu.)

Running the following commands on Xubuntu terminal creates the option in XFCE Window Manager settings to 'toggle' window borders. Unfortunately, I don't know about creating a keyboard shortcut, although with XFCE I'm certain you can easily do it. As it's very customizable and friendly.

```
sudo mkdir -p /usr/share/themes/empty/xfwm4
sudo touch /usr/share/themes/empty/xfwm4/themerc
```

As a tip, you might also want to consider tiling window managers. As this *might* fit your workflow or preference a little more. Something like i3wm/Xmonad/dwm is very customizable and takes time, but it's very much worth it. i3wm is well documented and tutorials are mostly in Ubuntu. Might be worth the shot.